# C: String Extraction from Pattern Match and Alternative Ways of String Termination?

Tags: c, regex, string, pattern-matching, posix

My question is two-fold:

I am using POSIX regular expressions and have a pretty good system set up to pattern match, and was working, but it's been very difficult dealing with C's low-level/difficult-to-use support for string operations, especially in the department of sub-string methods.  I know the following example isn't a vignette, so please bear with me, but I feel this section shows how I have set up the POSIX regular expression and how I am using it.  My primary question, how do I extract the string from POSIX for each pattern match and put inside a string/character array that I can safely use the normal C string functions such as those found here:  http://faculty.edcc.edu/paul.bladek/c_string_functions.htm?  It seems that I can get the string from the pattern matching internal struct, but C just dies every time I do what I feel are normal substring operations on the pattern match.

The following example shows code that has worked before, but up until i decided to change the variable "result" from an array to (char *) (you can see the old way commented out) and try to use C's memory allocation methods to do this right.  You can see in the output how far it gets, the variable "result" comes out correct, but then the program crashes at the IF comparison when I use strstr(...) for reasons I can't ascertain.

My last question, what is the best way to NULL terminate a (char *)?  Apparently, the way I am doing it below may be an issue.

Code:  (note, "storage" is a character array of a large size containing text that the pattern matching is being conducted upon)

```
regex_t r;  // stores regex
regmatch_t m[50];  // stores parts of file-string that matched the regex
const char * p = storage; // pointer to string that will be read in by regexec(...)
char matches[tracker][BUFFSIZE]; // 2D array containing a collection of strings
int ind = 0;  // indexing variable "matches" array
printf("### Collecting Pattern Matches ###\n");
int regExErr1 = regcomp(&r, "<[^<>]+=[[:space:]]*\"[^\"]+\"", REG_EXTENDED|REG_NEWLINE);
if( regExErr1 ){ 
    fprintf(stderr, "Fail to compile regex!\n"); 
    exit(1); 
}
while(1){
    regExErr1 = regexec(&r, p, 10, m, 0);
    if( regExErr1 != 0 ){ 
        fprintf(stderr, "Done finding URL pattern matches...\n"); 
        break; 
    }   
    int i = 0;
    while(1){
        if(m[i].rm_so == -1){
            break;
        }
        printf("entering loop at index %i\n", i);
        int start = m[i].rm_so;
        int finish = m[i].rm_eo;
        //char result[(finish - start)];
        char * result = (char *) malloc(strcspn(strstr(p + start, "<"), ">"));
        //strcpy(result, strstr(("%.*s\n", (finish - start), p + start), "<"));
        strcpy(result,("%.*s\n", strcspn((p+ start), ">"), strstr(p + start, "<")));
        result[strcspn(result, ">")+1] = 0;
        printf("LOOKING AT:  %s\n", result);
        if(strstr(result, "href") != NULL || strstr(result, "HREF") != NULL || strstr(result, "src") != NULL){
            printf("## CONSIDERING:  %s\n", result);
            if(strstr(result, "http:") == NULL && strstr(result, "mailto") == NULL){
                printf("Pattern is a relative URL.\n");
                strcpy(result, strstr(result, "\"") + 1);
                result[strcspn(result, "\"")] = 0;
                strcpy(result, relativePathCondense(result, "."));
                strcpy(matches[ind], base);
                strcat(matches[ind], result);
                matches[ind][(strlen(base) + strlen(result))] = 0; // NULL terminate the string match in the collection
                printf("Stored %i ==  %s\n", ind, matches[ind]);
                ...
                ind++; // update the counter to the 2D record array "matches"
            }else if(strstr(result, "http:") != NULL || strstr(result, "mailto:") != NULL){
                printf("Pattern is an absolute URL.\n");
                strcpy(result, strstr(result, "\"") + 1);
                result[strcspn(result, "\"")] = 0;
                printf("Trimmed expression is %s\n", result);
                strcpy(matches[ind], result);
                matches[ind][strlen(result)] = 0; // NULL terminate the string match in the collection
                printf("Stored %i ==  %s\n", ind, matches[ind]);
                ...
                ind++;                  
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
    p += m[0].rm_eo; // this will move the pointer p to the end of last matched pattern and on to the start of a new one
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
### Collecting URL's from stored HTML source document! ###
entering loop at index 0
LOOKING AT:  <BODY BGCOLOR = "#FFFFF0">
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    strcpy(result,("%.*s\n", strcspn((p+ start), ">"), strstr(p + start, "<")));
```

This does not do what you think...  The expression `("%.*s\n", ...` is just a use of the comma operator `expr, expr` which evaluates both expressions but has the value of the right-hand expr.  I think you meant to use `sprintf` here.

(Also without counting too closely you might be `malloc`ing one byte too few.  The usual idiom would be `strlen(s) + 1` but I'd have to think deeper about your `strspn`)

Comment: Hey Ben, that sprintf(...) is excellent.  And was exactly what I was looking for in terms of getting a string formatted a certain way into a (char *).  It is interesting that it exists outside of what's available `<string.h>` since it's from `<stdio.h>` but it works I was thinking the comma operator was working.  It definitely was instrumental in getting me to the solution.  It would be interesting to hear your thoughts on strspn(...) but what you proposed certainly took care of one issue that made my program crash.